# Understanding kernel build options (interpreters?)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am building a kernel for the first time for an embedded ARM platform. I am surprise that I can find options such as *games* and interpreters like *python* or *lua*.

Are they part of the kernel? Why such options are available on *menuconfig*?

Comment: Since it turns out you weren't building a kernel after all, this question is not meaningful.

Comment: Well, I agree, but I cannot delete it anymore :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel-x86 didnt have any python or lua.When you mentioned embedded ARM kernel.They built in into  embedded ARM kernel.I compiled kernel 2.4 until kenel 4.x.I didnt find this kind of options. Embedded Kernel was not standard kernel like Vanilla kernel for Android-x86

Comment: So it means, these options are part of the [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) framework. I might find some interesting information over there then.

Comment: @nowox So you're building a *Linux distribution*, not a kernel. That's the answer — not the post you commented on, which is gobbledygook.

Comment: I am building both actually and I discovered few hours ago the difference between `make menuconfig` and `make linux-menuconfig`. One is the kernel, the other the distribution and yes I was confused to see a `kernel` section in the distribution menuconfig.